# Does a BCY 425x string harm my tradtional recurve bow?

Tags: archery, bows

I've a Bear Archery Super Kodiak from 2013 with 40 #. I shoot 8,2 gpp arrows on it.

Recently I heard that I should not shoot a BCY 425x string on it since the high amount of vectran somehow harms my bow. Is this true? An if yes, how exactly is it harmful?

Answer (score 3):

it really depends on the bow tips and whether they are reinforced or not.  If it's a 2013 model, I suspect that it is fine.  Look at the tips, and if there is a 'reinforcement', as in if it has extra glued on material on the tips, then it has likely been made to allow the use of modern 'fastflight' type string materials.  You should also contact the manufacturer with the model number and ask them if it's safe to use modern string material, but I'd bet your fine if your limb tips are reinforced.

The warning is typically given to folks who have an older no reinforced tip bow, as the newer sting materials tend to be stronger and thinner, with less string stretch or creep, than Dacron (BCY500 type) or the other stuff.  I hae seen bows damadged by the newer stuff when the bow limb tips weren't reinforced or made for the new stuff, it will cut right through the at the nock shoulders.

Comment: Specifically, the limb needs a phenolic resin tip.  Wood reinforcement looks pretty, but is not sturdy enough to handle the shock of a low-stretch string.